# Using short author citations in bookdown/rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, bibtex, bookdown

In my report, I'm citing the *Standards for Educational and Psychological Testing* by AERA, APA, and NCME.

```
@Book{standards,
  title = {{Standards for Educational and Psychological Testing}},
  author = {{American Educational Research Association} and {American Psychological Association} and {National Council on Measurement in Education}},
  shortauthor = {AERA},
  publisher = {American Educational Research Association},
  address = {Washington, DC},
  year = {2014}
}
```

According to APA style guide 6th ed., recognizable abbreviations for authoring organizations should be used. The first time I'm citing this book in the text, it should look like this:

> Here is some filler text (American Educational Research Association
>   [AERA], American Psychological Association, & National Council
>   on Measurement in Education, 2014). And here is some more
>   filler text (AERA et al., 2014).

However, my citations are currently showing like this:

> Here is some filler text (American Educational Research Association,
>   American Psychological Association, & National Council on Measurement
>   in Education, 2014). And here is some more filler text (American
>   Educational Research Association et al., 2014).

Is there a way to implement these citations in **bookdown**? A minimally reproducible example is here: https://github.com/wjakethompson/bookdown-citations

Comment: Also useful for World Health Organization (WHO), Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC). Perhaps available if using [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47286/biblatex-abbreviating-authoring-organisations-in-citations); however, "shortauthor" in .bib doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to improve on the solution provided by Mikey Harper. It is still a partial solution only, since it uses LaTeX packages and therefore works only for PDF. The main idea is to use the [this LaTeX solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133700/problem-with-mkbibdateapalongextra-of-biblatex-apa) and adapt it to RMarkdown. Content of `test.bib`:

```
@Book{standards,
  title = {{Standards for Educational and Psychological Testing}},
  author = {{American Educational Research Association} and {American Psychological Association} and {National Council on Measurement in Education}},
  shortauthor = {{AERA et al.}},
  publisher = {American Educational Research Association},
  address = {Washington, DC},
  year = {2014}
}
```

Rmd file:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: test.bib
biblio-style: apa
biblatexoptions:
  - sortcites
header-includes:
  - \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}
---

[@standards]

[@standards]
```

Result:
[image]

This is not quite the requested format, since the short author is at the end of author list, but according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339668/biblatex-apa-how-to-correctly-use-multiple-shortauthors), there is no better solution. I have therefore opened https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/63.

Comment: Good work: happy to see there is no need for an external .tex file. Does this work with the original citation provided in the question with multiple authors?

Comment: @MikeyHarper Only partially. even with `shortauthor = {AERA and APA and NCME}` the abbreviations are not matched to their long forms.

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a partially working solution. This solution prints the long author and shortened version, **but only works for a single author**, and as it uses LaTeX to achieve the customisation, it **only works for PDF outputs**.

Adapting your provided example, I have created a bibliography `test.bib` as follows:

```
@Book{standards2,
  title = {{Standards for Educational and Psychological Testing}},
  author = {{American Educational Research Association}},
  shortauthor = {AERA},
  publisher = {American Educational Research Association},
  address = {Washington, DC},
  year = {2014}
}
```

A file `header.tex` is also created. This defines a new LaTeX command `\citefull`, which prints out a citation in the format `(author [shortauthor], year)`. The approach was loosely based off [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181302/biblatex-create-a-citejournal-command-with-journaltitle-date-title) here. The file content is as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefull}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   (\printnames{author}
   [\printnames{shortauthor}],
   {\printdate})
   }

  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% Adds a comma between the author and year
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Below is the Rmarkdown file. Changes are made to use biblatex as the citation package. To have a full citation, the command `\citefull{}` can be used.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header:  header.tex
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: test.bib
biblio-style: authoryear

---

\citefull{standards2}

[@standards2]
```

[image]

---

> ### Additional Notes
>
> As I said, this is a partial solution as it doesn't work for multiple
>   authors, and I must admit my knowledge of customising LaTeX citations
>   does not extend that far! Hopefully, someone will be able to expand on
>   this answer to be able to improve this functionality.
>
> I attempted using the solution [explained
>   here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47286/biblatex-abbreviating-authoring-organisations-in-citations),
>   but as it requires LaTeX packages to be loaded before biblatex, it
>   would require the altering of the pandoc .tex template. I felt this
>   was less optimal that using a header file.
>
> Even if I did edit the original template, I was still having problems
>   getting this solution working. I was getting an error
>   `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix` and wasn't able to work out where I
>   was messing things up.
>
> I hope these notes help anyone who considers exploring a better solution.